# Passing form with reference to itself

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have the following problem:

I have 2 windows forms ("Main" and "Form2") and separated class "PI".

Using panel, I display "Form2" inside "Main".

**Code from "Main"**:

```
Dim frm As new Form2 = Form2()
panel1.Controls.Add(frm)
frm.Show()
```

That's working fine. After clicking on the button from "Form2" the program went to class PI to do some calculations, this works fine also, but when all calculations from class PI are finished, I need to pass results back to the "Form2" using the following code (test is just string public variable). **Code from "PI":**

```
 Public Shared Sub Test
    Form2.test = "It works!"
end sub
```

**Code from "Form2":**

```
      Public test As String
        Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            PI.Test()
            MsgBox(test)
        End Sub
```

So, the problem is that without panel, if I open Form2 independently (not inside "Main", passing variables in this way works good (msgbox shows the statement), otherwise - it doesn't (empy box). Could you please tell me what is wrong and how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it works on standalone **Form2**:

In

```
Public Shared Sub Test()
    Form2.test = "It works!"
End Sub
```

you are always addressing default instance of **Form2**. It is that one you simply call as standalone in case you are describing as "works as expected".

But in your code

```vb
Dim frm As new Form2 = Form2()
    panel1.Controls.Add(frm)
frm.Show()
```

you are creating new (another) instance of your **Form2**.

Use the original default instance there (if you need only one **Form2**), i.e. do not use `new`, and it will start working.

```vb
panel1.Controls.Add(Form2)
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry for the stupid question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Structuring your code like this couples PI and Form2 together - they know too much about each other. Generally we prefer classes like PI to be independent from the UI code that uses them - it makes them easier to work with, reuse and debug.

I don't know what the result of the Test method is (in your example it's just a string), but you should make it so that the Test method returns it, then Form2 can use it.

If the result is more complicated (maybe it's several values) you could create a class to contain the result values and return an instance of that class from Test. Or you could just set multiple attributes on the PI instance and change the Form2 code to get the values from those attributes after calling Test. (This isn't as nice as returning the value, but it might be simpler, and it's much better than having PI set results on Form2 directly.)